# Change current folder

Tags: sas

I'd like to specify the current folder. I can find the current folder:

```
libname _dummy_ ".";
%let folder = %NRBQUOTE(%SYSFUNC(PATHNAME(_DUMMY_)));
%put &folder;
```

and change it manually by double clicking the current folder status bar, but I'd prefer to code it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
x 'cd <full path>';
```

for example

```
x 'cd C:\Users\foo';
```

SAS recognizes that a change directory command was issued to the OS and changes it's current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the timing of an `X` statement is like that of other global statements (title, footnote, options, etc).  If it is placed within a DATA step, the `X` statement will be issued prior to the data step execution.

For example, supposing your current working directory is `c:\temp`.  The following writes `HelloWorld.txt` to `c:\temp2` rather than `c:\temp`.  At compile time, SAS runs the `X` statement and *then* performs the data step.  Note that in SAS, a period (`.`) is the reference to the current working directory.

```
data _null_;
  file '.\HelloWorld.txt';
  put 'Hello, world!';
  x 'cd C:\temp2';
run;
```

To change directories *after* the data step has executed, you would want to use `CALL SYSTEM`. CALL statements execute conditionally by being called after a data step.

```
data _null_;
  file '.\HelloWorld.txt';
  put 'Hello, world!';
  command = 'cd "C:\temp2"';
  call system(command);
run;
```

More information about these kinds of details for Windows systems can be found in the [Running Windows or MS-DOS Commands from within SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n14rxpt7iu6iksn17r895o6kcpgi.htm)

Comment: I think the timing of the X statement is the same as other global statements (title, options, etc.)  Shouldn't be a difference between timing of X and %SYSCALL or %SYSEXEC.  Can you show an example of a difference?  I recognize if you put a global statement such as X inside of a data step, the global statement will be executed before the data step has even finished compiling, but that is the same with %syscall and %sysexec.

Comment: Windows Example would be great.  Understand that X statement is executed immediately.  I would expect same for %SYSCALL and %SYSEXEC and TITLE and OPTIONS and....

Comment: I believe you are correct.  I cannot produce an example which behaves otherwise.  Is that then what the X Statement documentation is referring to when it says, "SAS executes the X statement immediately"? I will update my answer. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-stmt-x.htm

Comment: Here is an extremely esoteric example, but one which does illustrate a difference between the `x` statement and using `%syscall system()`.  The current working directory must be a UNC path on a network.  This happens to me when working from a network file which is not currently mapped (i.e. it begins with a \\ ).  In such a case, `%Test()` shows the UNC error `CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.  UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.` The error seems to appear be because the `x` statement executes immediately (before `temp` is assigned).

Comment: `%macro Test();
  %let temp = %sysfunc(pathname(WORK)); 
  data _null_;
    file "&temp.\HelloWorld.txt";
    put 'Hello, world!';
  run;
  option xwait;
  x 'cd "&temp."';
  %sysexec(type "&temp.\HelloWorld.txt");
 
%mend;
%Test();
%macro Test2();
  %let temp = %sysfunc(pathname(WORK)); 
  data _null_;
    file "&temp.\HelloWorld.txt";
    put 'Hello, world!';
  run;
  option xwait;
  %let cmd  = cd "&temp";
  %syscall system(cmd);
  %sysexec(type "&temp.\HelloWorld.txt");
%mend;
%Test2();`

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see now the X could be executed before the %LET statement that comes before it.  Will have to play with this a bit and see if I can replicate. Thx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143542/discussion-between-lorem-ipsum-and-quentin).